# I need to help this site reach beta? It's already in beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase

The message about helping a site reach beta is still shown [on the WebApps proposal.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57?phase=commitment) I'm not sure whether this overlaps with [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55506/receive-invitation-e-mail-but-the-site-says-this-site-is-currently-in-private-b) but I posted it separately as it should be a lot easier to repro.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed.